# Highcharts: Adding extra text to legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

Hi all I have a pie chart with the legend format like this:

```
{
    enabled: true,
    labelFormatter: function() {
        return  this.name + ' (Gesamt: ' + this.y + ' - '  + this.percentage.toFixed(1) + '%)' ;
    },
    borderWidth: 1
};
```

In some specific cases, I need to add an extra text which I defined as text = 'Extra' to this legend box. The rest legends I still keep them in the box. How can I do that ?

My jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/wjnnt28p/

Comment: What is "specific cases"?

Comment: this happens in my actual code, in the jsfiddle I just put an example

Answer (score 3):

You can add some if condition and display text like you want.

e.g.

```
labelFormatter: function() {
  var p = this.name + ' (Gesamt: ' + this.y + ' - ' + this.percentage.toFixed(1) + '%)';
  if (this.name == 'Chrome') { // Test the name
    return p + ' Other Text for Chrome';
  } else {
    return p;
  }
}
```

Full example :

```js
$(function () {

  $(document).ready(function () {

    var text = 'Extra';

    // Build the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          },
          showInLegend: true
        }
      },

      legend: {
        enabled: true,
        labelFormatter: function () {
          var p = this.name + ' (Gesamt: ' + this.y + ' - ' + this.percentage.toFixed(1) + '%)';
          if (this.name == 'Chrome') { // Test the name
            return p + ' Other Text for Chrome';
          } else {
            return p;
          }
        },
        borderWidth: 1
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
          name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
          y: 56.33
        }, {
          name: 'Chrome',
          y: 24.03,
          sliced: true,
          selected: true
        }, {
          name: 'Firefox',
          y: 10.38
        }, {
          name: 'Safari',
          y: 4.77
        }, {
          name: 'Opera',
          y: 0.91
        }, {
          name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
          y: 0.2
        }]
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: No I mean I still keep all the current legends and then add one more addition text

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**  [**fiddle with empty series,extra legend**](http://jsfiddle.net/wjnnt28p/14/) (Latest with datalabel enabled)

you are almost there, use this >> put a field like "extra" in your series data .

**Updated**

```
           labelFormatter: function() {
                  if(this.extra !=null){
                    return  this.name + ' ('+this.extra+': ' + this.y + ' - '                                                   + this.percentage.toFixed(1) + '%)' ;
                }else{
                   return  this.name + '(' + this.y + ' - '                                                     + this.percentage.toFixed(1) + '%)' ;
                }}
```

[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wjnnt28p/3/)

put a if condition to get rid of undefined .

**As per comment below**

create a empty series with the name "Extra" **OR** do like following

```
 labelFormatter: function() { if(this.y ==null) return "Extra Legend"; jsfiddle.net/wjnnt28p/4
```

the catch is , as you are formatting legend,if y don't have any value it will show undefined text. (Empty series case) for that write conditional logic there.

Second solution is to return "Extra label" but click of this legend won't have data,so legendclick could be override .

Comment: @Son Plz check the fiddle in my answer. your series would be dynamic/ coming from a server call as a response. So best is to add your extraText in data while JSON creating and provide it to highcharts. At chart , it will show in desired format using the the code I posted in answer/fiddle. putting static text for "Extra" won't work in real scenario, so use the code in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wjnnt28p/3/.

Comment: The problem is what I would like to display is the additional text which will be shown as a new legend, besides the current legends like Microsoft Internet Explore, Chrome, Firefox,... That means my new legend box will content : Microsoft Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, Proprietary or Undetectable and Extra

Comment: for that, just create a empty series with the name "Extra" or do like  labelFormatter: function() {
                      if(this.y ==null) return "Extra Legend";  http://jsfiddle.net/wjnnt28p/4/

Comment: creating an empty series is a great idea but if without y data, then the chart will be no longer display, only the legends are displayed

Comment: @Son see this http://jsfiddle.net/wjnnt28p/6/ all series are displayed,extra legend is displayed

Comment: remove additional text - Hi,hello,Another etc from formatter function as you don't want them http://jsfiddle.net/wjnnt28p/7/

Comment: ah I see one more the problem, if now I enable the datalabels in the plotoptions and set the format to: '{point.name}: {point.percentage:.1f} %'. Then I will see the Extra Legend display as the label. I dont want this Extra Legend to be displayed. Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/wjnnt28p/8/

Comment: Problem is splved now, you are expert in Highcharts. Many thanks Nishith !